# how to convert string of bytes string into string using python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, byte

I got a string of bytes string like below:

string1 = "b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe4\xbb\xac \xe7\xb4\xa2\xe8\xa6\x81 \xe6\x8e\xa8\xe5\xb9\xbf \xe7\x9a\x84 \xe6\x98\xaf\xe4\xb8\x80 \xe5\xbe\x97 \xe6\x96\xb9\xe6\x96\xb9 \xe6\x96\xb9\xe8\xa8\x80 \xe4\xb8\xba\xe5\x9f\xba \xe7\xa1\x80 \xe6\x96\xb9\xe8\xa8\x80 \xe4\xb8\x80 \xe5\x8c\x97\xe4\xba\xac \xe5\xb7\xb2 \xe5\x9b\xa0 \xe4\xb8\xba \xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86 \xe7\x9a\x84 \xe6\x99\xae\xe9\x80\x9a \xe8\xaf\x9d \xe4\xbb\x96 \xe4\xbb\x8e \xe5\x84\xbf\xe7\xab\xa5 \xe6\x97\xb6\xe4\xbb\xa3 \xe8\xb5\xb7 \xe5\xb0\xb1 \xe5\x96\x9c\xe6\xac\xa2 \xe4\xb8\x8b \xe5\x9b\xb4\xe6\xa3\x8b \xe5\x9c\xa8 \xe5\x8d\x81\xe4\xba\x94 \xe5\xb2\x81 \xe7\x9a\x84 \xe6\x97\xb6\xe5\x80\x99 \xe5\xb0\xb1 \xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\x9c\x89 \xe5\x90\x8d \xe5\x85\xb6 \xe5\xb0\x91 \xe4\xba\x86'"

I want to convert string of bytes string into string so that i could use decode function to normal result.

Comment: Can you not just do `new_string = st[2:-1]` ?

Comment: This should work too `str(string1)` if there is a problem you are facing trying to implement mine or RMRiver's solutions, please edit your question to explain that.

Answer (score 3):

First, put an `r` before it so that the `\x` keeps both characters. Then ast.literal_eval() will work.

```py
import ast

string1 = r"b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe4\xbb\xac \xe7\xb4\xa2\xe8\xa6\x81 \xe6\x8e\xa8\xe5\xb9\xbf \xe7\x9a\x84 \xe6\x98\xaf\xe4\xb8\x80 \xe5\xbe\x97 \xe6\x96\xb9\xe6\x96\xb9 \xe6\x96\xb9\xe8\xa8\x80 \xe4\xb8\xba\xe5\x9f\xba \xe7\xa1\x80 \xe6\x96\xb9\xe8\xa8\x80 \xe4\xb8\x80 \xe5\x8c\x97\xe4\xba\xac \xe5\xb7\xb2 \xe5\x9b\xa0 \xe4\xb8\xba \xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86 \xe7\x9a\x84 \xe6\x99\xae\xe9\x80\x9a \xe8\xaf\x9d \xe4\xbb\x96 \xe4\xbb\x8e \xe5\x84\xbf\xe7\xab\xa5 \xe6\x97\xb6\xe4\xbb\xa3 \xe8\xb5\xb7 \xe5\xb0\xb1 \xe5\x96\x9c\xe6\xac\xa2 \xe4\xb8\x8b \xe5\x9b\xb4\xe6\xa3\x8b \xe5\x9c\xa8 \xe5\x8d\x81\xe4\xba\x94 \xe5\xb2\x81 \xe7\x9a\x84 \xe6\x97\xb6\xe5\x80\x99 \xe5\xb0\xb1 \xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\x9c\x89 \xe5\x90\x8d \xe5\x85\xb6 \xe5\xb0\x91 \xe4\xba\x86'"
bytes1 = ast.literal_eval(string1)
print(bytes1.decode('utf8'))  # 我们 索要 ...
```

Comment: did you try your solution? because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ThunderCoder I tried it and it does work

Comment: @BoarGules, look here:https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/nLLLyLwNxZ to understand why I said that.

Comment: I copied your code, the this link: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/nLLLyLwNxZ, and it doesn't seem to work there

Comment: @ThunderCoder I looked there. You did not attempt to convert the bytes to a string, which is what OP wants. Try `bytes1.decode()` to see what I mean.

Comment: @BoarGules, if that needs to be done, it should be shown in the answer. I copied and pasted it.

Comment: @ThunderCoder Question says *so that I could use decode function*.